Custom Google Sheets Appscripts Function Issue:
Currently trying to figure out how to create a custom google sheets function that:

Takes a given range such as a column like C4:C13 for example,
Goes through each cell and checks if any of the given values within the cell, (which are all monetary values, no strings), have a strike through or not,
Returns the sum of each value that has strike through, (not total amount of cells with strikethrough).

For example, C4 = '$240.00', C5 = '$30.00' (strikethrough), C6 = '$650.00', C7 = '$90.00' (strikethrough), C8 = '$5.00'. The function should loop through these cells and return '$120.00'.
From the experimenting and trying to troubleshoot my script, the result throws different errors that don't make sense or don't really help me figure out how to move further.
Some of these errors include:

Exception: Range not found.
Type: Function (like .getRange() or .getValue()) does not exist.

This is what I have so far:
function SUM_STRIKETHROUGH(range) {
    //if (!range || !range.length) {
    //  return 'Invalid range';
    //}

    var sum = 0;
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range2 = sheet.getRange(range)
    var value = range2.getValue();

    for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < range[i].length; j++) {
            if (value.getValue.isStrikethrough()) {
                sum += value.getValue;
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

// Refreshes the custom function every time the sheet is edited.

function onEdit(e) {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var formulas = range.getFormulas();
    for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < formulas[i].length; j++) {
            if (formulas[i][j].indexOf('SUM_STRIKETHROUGH') !== -1) {
                var rangeString = formulas[i][j].replace('=SUM_STRIKETHROUGH(', '').replace(')', '');
                var rangeArray = sheet.getRange(rangeString);
                var rangeValues = rangeArray.getValues(); // get the actual values
                sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).setValue(SUM_STRIKETHROUGH(rangeValues));
            }
        }
    }
}

onEdit() trigger is in place to update the cell whenever a cell within the given range is updated.
Apologies in advanced about formatting and inconsistencies, first post on stack overflow.
I have some programming knowledge but not enough javascript experience to build the script myself successfully.
Thank you in advance.

Would you please edit the question to include some sample data and an example of the expected outcome.

Related question: Detect whether a cell has strikethrough format on Webapps.

Earlier (and now deleted) I said "The custom function will update automatically if any cell in the input range is manually edited". Argh... WRONG! Anyone who thinks this is true should read this by  Henrique G. Abreu regarding the Google caching bug. And this answer by @TheMaster on the using the onChange trigger to update custom formula (but use the FORMAT change type). Both are from Refresh data retrieved by a custom function in Google Sheet.

1) Would you explain why the script includes an onEdit trigger (Refreshes the custom function every time the sheet is edited.) 2) Are you trying to detect whether/when cells in the input range have a change in their strikethrough status?

This looks more like a job listing than a question about a specific problem unique to programming. You should include the textual error messages. P.D. It's essential to know that Google Apps Script uses JavaScript as a programming language.

Adapted from Detect whether a cell has strikethrough format
For each value of "lines" (var lines = range.getFontLines()) there is an equivalent "cell value" (var values = range.getValues()).
So if a line value = "line-through" (if (lines[i][j] == 'line-through')), then the array parameters (i & j) applied to the "values" array will return the corresponding value(values[i][j]) which value can be added to a counter (sumofStrikethrough = sumofStrikethrough + values[i][j]).

/**
 * Sums strikethough values
 *
 * @param {A1 or C4:C13} input The range of cells to evaluate.
 * @return sum of values with FontLine value of 'line-through'
 * 
 * @customfunction
 */
function SUM_STRIKETHROUGH(input) {
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var fParts=formula.split(')').shift()
  var rang=fParts.split('(').pop()
 

  try {
    var range = sheet.getRange(rang);
  }
  catch(e) {
    throw new Error(args[1] + ' is not a valid range');
  }
  var values = range.getValues()
  var lines = range.getFontLines();
  var sumofStrikethrough = 0  
  for (var i in lines) {
    for (var j in lines[i]) {
      Logger.log("i:"+i+", j:"+j+", line value:"+lines[i][j]+", value:"+values[i][j]);
      if (lines[i][j] == 'line-through'){
        sumofStrikethrough = sumofStrikethrough + values[i][j]
      }
    }
  }
  return sumofStrikethrough;
}


h/t: @JasonWilson. Webapps: Adapted from Detect whether a cell has strikethrough format

This works great! Thank you for your help. Turns out I don't exactly need the onEdit() trigger, all I really need to do is just delete the cell and ctrl+z.
